# FFImageLoading image is not displaying

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I notice that when I open a page for the first time it's loading the image and adding it to the cache. So for a brief time, you can't see the image. The next time that I open the page the image will show instantly. Is there a way to "preload" the images before they are shown on the page so that they will be shown instantly the first time as well?

Every time image is caching with new GUID. and my images are not getting cached.

Total images are 4 and some images are 2-3 times cached
I don't know why I tried to debug it, I didn't get any solution.

please help me.

My Offerlistview.xaml Code:

```
<img:SvgCachedImage x:Name="ImageFront" 
                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                    Aspect="AspectFill"
                                    ErrorPlaceholder="mcdonalds"
                                    LoadingDelay="3000"
                                    HeightRequest="205"
                                    WidthRequest="350"
                                    Margin="0"
                                    DownsampleToViewSize="False"
                                    DownsampleUseDipUnits="True"
                                    RetryCount="3"/>
```

My Offerlistview.xaml.cs Code:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty BImageProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BImage), typeof(ImageSource), typeof(OffersListView), null, BindingMode.TwoWay, null, ImageSourcePropertyChanged);

        public ImageSource BImage
        {
            get { return (ImageSource) GetValue(BImageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BImageProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void ImageSourcePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var control = (OffersListView)bindable;
            control.ImageFront.Source = (ImageSource)newValue;
        }

public static readonly BindableProperty ImageGIFProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ImageGIF), typeof(ImageSource), typeof(OffersListView), null, BindingMode.TwoWay, null, ImagePlaceholderPropertyChanged);

        public ImageSource ImageGIF
        {
            get { return (ImageSource) GetValue(ImageGIFProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImageGIFProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void ImagePlaceholderPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var control = (OffersListView)bindable;
            control.ImageFront.LoadingPlaceholder = (ImageSource)newValue;
        }

<img:SvgCachedImage x:Name="ImageFront" 
                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                    Aspect="AspectFill"
                                    ErrorPlaceholder="mcdonalds"
                                    LoadingDelay="3000"
                                    HeightRequest="205"
                                    WidthRequest="350"
                                    Margin="0"
                                    DownsampleToViewSize="False"
                                    DownsampleUseDipUnits="True"
                                    RetryCount="3"/>
```

This is my XAML code.

I want that first GIF should be displayed and when my images are loaded successfully ten it should be displayed but it is displaying only 1 image or nothing sometimes.

This is my Dummy Code:

### ProductList.xaml

```
 <ScrollView  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" 
                                    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource BgColor-WhiteSmoke}" 
                                    Margin="0,0,0,10" >
                            <StackLayout x:Name="stackFrontImage" Padding="0" HeightRequest="100" Spacing="0" Margin="10" IsVisible="True">
                                <controls:OfferView ImageGIF="outlet" BImage="{Binding MPImages}" />
                                <controles:BindableLabelLayout x:Name="stackBindControl" LContent="{Binding MPContent}" />
                            </StackLayout>

                        </ScrollView>
```

### Offerview.xaml (Controls)

```
 <Frame WidthRequest="350" HeightRequest="180" HasShadow="True"
                    CornerRadius="10" Padding="0" Margin="15,15,0,10" BorderColor="{StaticResource BgColor-White}">

            <StackLayout Padding="0" Spacing="0" Margin="0">
                <!--<Image x:Name="ItemImage" 
                       Source="{Binding ImageGIF}"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                       Aspect="AspectFill"
                       IsVisible="False"/>-->
                <img:SvgCachedImage x:Name="ImageFront" 
                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                    Aspect="AspectFill"
                                    Source="{Binding BImage}"
                                    LoadingPlaceholder="{Binding ImageGIF}"
                                    Margin="0"/>

            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
```

### Offerview.xaml.cs

```
#region Source image bindingproperty

        public static readonly BindableProperty BImageProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BImage), typeof(ImageSource), typeof(OfferView), null, BindingMode.TwoWay, null, ImageSourcePropertyChanged);

        public ImageSource BImage
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(BImageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BImageProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void ImageSourcePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var control = (OfferView)bindable;
            control.ImageFront.Source = (ImageSource)newValue;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Source gif image bindingproperty

        public static readonly BindableProperty ImageGIFProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ImageGIF), typeof(ImageSource), typeof(OfferView), null, BindingMode.TwoWay, null, ImagePlaceholderPropertyChanged);

        public ImageSource ImageGIF
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageGIFProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImageGIFProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void ImagePlaceholderPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var control = (OfferView)bindable;
            control.ImageFront.LoadingPlaceholder = (ImageSource)newValue;
        }

        #endregion
```

That's all my Dummy project code where I am trying to get response and response is coming but whole images are not loading please help m out.

Comment: Are your Images name are created dynamically... Image Uri = http://dynamic.png ...then every-time ffimageloading plugin will create a new cache.... FFImageLoading provides a service using which you can PreLoad Image before rendering / navigating to actual page....    "ImageService"  you can simply call in your shared project... ImageSerive.Instance.* (LoadUrl, LoadImage) ... LoadUrl method when you want to preload Image from rest api / web ... LoadImage method when you want to load Image from your resource... Hope this helps ...let me know if any query

Comment: @Hamid Shaikh yes my image is loading here dynamically but i am unable to load my images it is displaying and then disappearing again and again and when i am putting debugger off and then directly opening an app then all the images are showing here tell me and please help me out that how i can achieve this.

Comment: i think you can try with simple declaration like this <img:SvgCachedImage x:Name="ImageFront" 
                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                    Aspect="AspectFill"
                                    HeightRequest="205"
                                    WidthRequest="350"/> ... and check if this resolves the issue and later try adding other properties one by one to analyse / identify the property which is giving you such result...

Comment: @ Hamid Shaikh  i have already tried these options but it is not working.

Comment: If possible can you create project which reproduce this issue and share it ? so people can have a look and help you out

Comment: @Hamid Shaikh I have already done this on another (Dummy) Project but it is not working.please tell me another way to do this.

Comment: Can you upload your dummy project and share the download link...so we can have a look.